# How does a recursive function with two recursive calls work?

Tags: c++

I am currently reading a C++ guide and I am on the recursion section right now and I am a bit confused about how the process works for this certain problem. Here is the code from the book example:

```
void subdivide(char ar[], int low, int high, int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
        return;
    int mid = (high + low)/2;
    ar[mid] = '|';
    subdivide(ar, low, mid, level - 1); // #1
    subdivide(ar, mid, high, level -1); // #2
}
```

So far I understand that the #1 recursive call keeps going until the base case is 0 and then finally #2 recursive call happens. However, when we first activate the #2 call wouldn't it also activate #1 call?? Or does the #1 call permanently stop working after it's done so that every time we recurse with #2 it skips #1 and goes to the #2 call?

Comment: _"How does a recursive function with two recursive calls work?"_ Not well, unless it sees values changing `void subdivide(char ar[], int &low, int &high, int &level)`

Comment: Does the book not explain it? I'm assuming you're reading [C++ primer](https://books.google.com/books?id=eC-iLe_iET8C&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=void+subdivide%28char+ar[],+int+low,+int+high,+int+level%29&source=bl&ots=HXjEOjQWl4&sig=yQNqdeEHy87jwDX14weOLMPhxKs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jW6cVNLiNoyiNu_egqgB&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=void%20subdivide%28char%20ar[]%2C%20int%20low%2C%20int%20high%2C%20int%20level%29&f=false).

Comment: So does the #2 call activate the #1?

Comment: @TakShing Read the paragraph under **Program Notes**. The explanation look sufficient to me.

Comment: It does explain it, but it doesn't explain whether or not #1 activates when #2 is called. I know that when we call #1 is called, #2 can't be activated until #1 is finished.

Comment: So if level is 3, that means #1 is first called 3 times and when it reaches 0 it goes to #2, which activates and from there #1 is called again?

Comment: @TakShing #1 will *always* activate so long as the bail-out predicate `(level == 0)` is **not** met. And #2 will *always* activate after #1 has returned. It really is that simple. A `printf` at the head of the function and two immediately preceding both recursive calls would do *wonders* in hands-on demonstrating the flow of execution, as would a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call dosnt stop working permanently. The call to #1 function is made again, everytime when second (#2) executes.
Also when #1 executes it makes call to #1 and #2 and so on.

Comment: When we execute #1, #2 only activates when the base case for #1 is 0 though right?

Comment: When #1 is called the function executed again , so again #1 is called. Then again the function executes , #1 is called till level is 0. When level becomes 0 the function return and all the remaining #2 will execute one by one.

Comment: Also the order in which #2 is LIFO(Last in first out) because the function calls are stored in a STACK. And a stack is LIFO

Comment: When #1 executes, how does it make a call to #2?

Comment: When #1 executes the entire function is called again , so the entire function executes , including #1 and #2 also.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=BnicVNCMI5GRuAT93IGICQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DozmE8G6YKww&ved=0CBwQtwIwAA&usg=AFQjCNHBRc5tvKKPBJmsJNa5DmY6kj6y8A&sig2=Lc6uihP4yh_y-JYCLhtBcA

Comment: Watch this video , you ll understand better!

Answer (score 0):

When you recurse into #2, the entire function is executed again, with the new values of arguments. This means that #1 is not skipped (unless `level` is `0`, in which case the function returns immediately).

Answer (score 0):

The entire function runs again when you recurse, with different initial state (the arguments, and any changes made).

What ends up running is a 'tree' of recursive calls -- two to the power of level, roughly -- but no recursion goes further than `level` deep.

"paint a fence, if it is one board, paint it top to bottom.  Otherwise, divide the fence in two left to right along a board edge.  Paint the left half, then the right, using this algorithm."

This describes in English a similar recursive structure.  In your case, we divide your range in two, pit a divider marker in the middle, then repeat on each half.